# Flutter/Dart SocketException Uploading Video File to URL

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, upload, mux

I am recieving this error message when attempting to upload a video file to the speicified URL:

```
DioError (DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54, address = storage.googleapis.com, port = 64995)
```

*Note: It is a `DioError` as I am using the `dio` Dart/Flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/dio I recieve the error using equivilent API such as the `http` library.*

Code to upload the video file selected from storage:

```
        //File videoFile...

        FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
          "videoFile": await MultipartFile.fromFile(videoFile.path),
        });
    
        Response response = await Dio().post(
          directUpload.url,
          data: data,
          onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
            print("$sent $total");
          },
        );
```

The URL (`directUpload.url`) is one generated from and provided by the Mux API to their Google Cloud Storage.

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/video-storage-us-east1-uploads/...
```

When `post` is called, a small amount is uploaded (e.g. 655524 / 17840042) and then the error occurs. The test video is 17.8 Mb in size.

Running this on an iOS device or the iOS simulator produces the same result/error.

---

I have tried: `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, deleteing `Podfile` and `pod repo update`, deleting the app from device. All to no avail.

Comment: look at the headers required by the URL, and the ones you are providing, might be keep-alive header missing!

Comment: @Yadu No change adding the `connection: keep-alive` header.

Comment: Keep-Alive, see the caps!

Comment: Still get the error. My understanding is the header is not case-sensitive anyway.

Comment: today is the day i learned that :), i would rather use the default streams and HttpClient rather than http and dio, as the error states it might be internal error on the server, OS error!

Comment: Maybe servers hosting the Flutter SDK components are blocked. Please check

Comment: Try this: flutter pub cache repair

Comment: did you try reinstalling the app also,  try uploading a small file (maybe 10 MB) to see if it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change from a POST to a PUT request resolves the issue.

Comment: for me the Dio error only happens every 1/10 times, was it the same case for you?
Also why did PUT fix the problem?

Comment: Worked for me too, i was uploading to AWS bucket

Answer (score 2):

yes, I have same problem with Dio.

current can't upload data type `Uint8List`

My temporary solution:
use [http lib](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
`http: ^0.12.1`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future uploadData(Uint8List imageData) async {
    await http.put(preData.url, headers: getHeader(), body: imageData);
}

use:
List<int> imageData = File(filePath).readAsBytesSync();
await uploadData(imageData);
```

hope to help you

Comment: Changing to the `http` lib isn't the solution. However, changing from a `POST` to `PUT` request using either lib does.

Answer (score 2):

The error message "Connection reset by peer" appears, if the web services client was waiting for a SOAP response from the remote web services provider and the connection was closed prematurely.

One of the most common causes for this error is a firewall in the middle closing the connection. In this case you could increase the connection timeout in the firewall.You can find the component that closes the connection by capturing and analyzing an IP trace.

Other possible causes are e.g.:

- resource limitations on the server side like out of memory server
- process killed
- overload on the server due to a high amount of traffic

ALSO Try this..

```
cd ~/flutter
git checkout -b max-in-flight
code packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/devfs.dart # edit kMaxInFlight from 6 to 1
rm bin/cache/flutter_tools*
```

AND This

```
flutter clean
flutter channel stable
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `http.MultipartRequest`  method ?
As it can be used to transfer large files, you can also try is DIO alternative if present in `dio`
and how to use http.MultipartRequest here is an article https://dev.to/carminezacc/advanced-flutter-networking-part-1-uploading-a-file-to-a-rest-api-from-flutter-using-a-multi-part-form-data-post-request-2ekm

let me know if it works or not.

Comment: `http.MultipartRequest` produces the same result.

Comment: I faced with "Payload Too Large " error by using http.MultipartRequest

Answer (score 0):

When post is called, a small amount is uploaded (e.g. 655524 / 17840042) and then the error occurs. The test video is 17.8 Mb in size.

Answer-

Go your cpanel MultiPHP INI Editor file and increase post_max_size

No need to change u r flutter code, it is right .